# MYSQL: many-to-many (Item x_ref Property) WHERE Item does not contain Property

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables; a table of items, a table of properties and an x_ref table which links the items to the properties and also contains a value for that property:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `item_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 row_format=COMPRESSED; 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `properties` (
  `property_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `property_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,    
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 row_format=COMPRESSED;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item_xref_properties` (
  `item_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `property_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,   
  `property_value` DECIMAL(8,1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`item_id`,`property_id`),
  INDEX (`item_id`),
  INDEX (`property_id`),
  INDEX (`property_value_1`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 row_format=COMPRESSED;
```

I have query like this:

*fetch all items that contains properties 'A', 'B' and 'C' where
'A' is between 100 and 200
'B' is between 50 and 80
'C' is between 10 and 30*

Which translates to:

```
SELECT itm.item_id 
FROM items itm 
    JOIN item_types ityp 
        ON itm.type_id = ityp.type_id
   JOIN item_xref_properties ixp1 
        ON itm.item_id = ixp1.item_id 
            AND ixp1.property_value 
            BETWEEN '100' AND '200' 
   JOIN properties prop1 
        ON ixp1.property_id = prop1.property_id 
            AND prop1.property_name = 'Property A' 
   JOIN item_xref_properties ixp2 
        ON itm.item_id = ixp2.item_id 
            AND ixp2.property_value 
            BETWEEN '50' AND '80' 
   JOIN properties prop2 
        ON ixp2.property_id = prop2.property_id 
            AND prop2.property_name = 'Property B' 
   JOIN item_xref_properties ixp3 
        ON itm.item_id = ixp3.item_id 
            AND ixp3.property_value_1 
            BETWEEN '10' AND '30' 
   JOIN properties prop3 
        ON ixp3.property_id = prop3.property_id 
            AND prop3.property_name = 'Property C'
```

Pretty straight forward if a little inelegant.

My problem is I need to query this table as above and also find items that ***don't*** have specified properties like this:

*Fetch all items that contains properties 'A', 'B' and 'C' where
'A' is between 100 and 200
'B' is between 50 and 80
'C' is between 10 and 30 
But **don't** contain properties 'D' or 'E'*

I've tried many ways to translate this to a working query but to no avail. Is this even possible? Or am I going to have to flatten the tables and just have separate columns in item table for each property (not ideal as there are over a 100 properties and the list can possibly grow in the future)

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Hint: 'OUTER' joins and 'CASE' statements.

Comment: Hmm, not sure where I would use 'CASE'. I think there should be an outer join on the Properties table followed by a test for null, but I can't quite put it all together. Any other hints?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the terse and misleading reply.

Looking at it again, I see UNIONs:

```
SELECT itm.item_id 
FROM items itm 
    JOIN item_types ityp 
        ON itm.type_id = ityp.type_id
   JOIN item_xref_properties ixp1 
        ON itm.item_id = ixp1.item_id 
            AND ixp1.property_value 
            BETWEEN '100' AND '200' 
   JOIN properties prop1 
        ON ixp1.property_id = prop1.property_id 
            AND prop1.property_name = 'Property A' 
UNION
SELECT itm.item_id 
FROM items itm 
    JOIN item_types ityp 
        ON itm.type_id = ityp.type_id
    JOIN item_xref_properties ixp2 
        ON itm.item_id = ixp2.item_id 
            AND ixp2.property_value 
            BETWEEN '50' AND '80' 
   JOIN properties prop2 
        ON ixp2.property_id = prop2.property_id 
            AND prop2.property_name = 'Property B' 
UNION
SELECT itm.item_id 
FROM items itm 
    JOIN item_types ityp 
        ON itm.type_id = ityp.type_id
    JOIN item_xref_properties ixp3 
        ON itm.item_id = ixp3.item_id 
            AND ixp3.property_value_1 
            BETWEEN '10' AND '30' 
   JOIN properties prop3 
        ON ixp3.property_id = prop3.property_id 
            AND prop3.property_name = 'Property C'
```

You're also joining from items to item_types, but doing nothing with the info (just confirming that the item.type_id is a valid value?).  You can probably take that out.

Then, if all you're after is the item_id, you can get that from each visit to the item_xref_properties_table without going to the items table at all, which will make things nicer.

Hope that's more useful.